# Regex expression to select pair of lines

Tags: regex, editor, expression

I have a logfile. Its general format is

```
log text 1  <br/>
log text 2  <br/>
Error: xxxxxx  <br/>
error description (1 line only)  <br/>
log text 3 <br/>
log text 4  <br/>
....  <br/>
Error: xxxxxx  <br/>
error description (1 line only)  <br/>
log text 5  <br/>
....  <br/>
```

I would like to select and extract pair of 2 lines containing errors (each error has two lines. The first line always has Error: as keyword. Word Error does not occur anywhere else in logfile).

How do I do it using regex or any other way. I can use MacOS, Unix or Windows XP. MacOS preferred.

Comment: What editor program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using grep on mac or unix based OS

```
grep -i error -A2 inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression to find those 2 lines is for example:

```
^.*?Error.*(?:\r?\n|\r).*$
```

`^` ... start each search at beginning of a line.

`.*?` ... match any character except carriage return and line-feed zero or more times non greedy. Non greedy means as less characters as possible. In other words stop on first occurrence of `Error` and not on last occurrence.

`Error` ... this word must be found in the first of 2 lines to match.

`.*` ... match any character except carriage return and line-feed zero or more times greedy. Greedy means now match as many characters as possible.

`(?:\r?\n|\r)` ... is a non-marking group matching either carriage return + line-feed (DOS/Windows text files), or only line-feed (UNIX text files), or only carriage return (old MAC text file).

`.*` ... match any character except carriage return and line-feed 0 or more times greedy.

`$` ... anchor for end of line. Line termination is not included in matched string.

In other words this expression matches an entire line containing anywhere the word `Error`, the line terminator of this first line and everything on next line up to end of line, but not matching also the line terminator of this second line.

*UltraEdit* is a shareware text editor available for Windows, Linux and Mac.

Using this **Perl** regular expression in **Search - Find** dialog of *UltraEdit* with advanced find option *List lines containing string* enabled results in getting all found 2 line strings written to a window listing all found lines.

Opening the context menu of this window (right click on Windows) and clicking on **Copy to Clipboard** results in copying all found lines to system clipboard.

Pressing Ctrl+N to open a new file, Ctrl+V to paste the copied lines, and Ctrl+S to save the new file results finally in having a file with the wanted information.

Another method is using the *UltraEdit* script [FindStringsToNewFile](https://www.ultraedit.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=12866) with the reduced regular expression search string `Error.*(?:\r?\n|\r).*`. This script writes all found strings starting with keyword `Error` and ending at end of next line directly to a new file.

One more note:

If a `.` (dot) matches also newline characters like carriage return and line-feed depends on a flag. In *UltraEdit* the flag is by default set that a dot does not match newline characters. With `(?s)` at beginning of a Perl regular expression search string the flag is changed and the dot would then match also newline characters for this search. With `(?-s)` at beginning of a search string the flag can be set for not matching newline characters by a dot if the internal default of the application is the opposite.